Oracle Linux allows individual packages to be updated but not all
Running sudo yum update -y, returns error "You need to update rpm to handle: rpmlib (PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1", even though rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest has been run with no output.
I have also tried sudo yum clean all.
I haven't successfully updated epel.
This host runs OpenOTP if that helps.
I can, however, update individual packages with commands like yum update python-perf -y, but I prefer to avoid that for 30 packages every month.
Any help would be appreciated!.
=========================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade  34 Packages
Remove               ( 1 Dependent package)

Total size: 722 M
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
ERROR You need to update rpm to handle:
rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1 is needed by selfreg-1.4.3-5.noarch
RPM needs to be updated
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2024-10-30.02-59.6qJwKy.yumtx```


Try to update first (by hand) rpmlib and then try to update all.

What version of Oracle Linux?  Where exactly did you get that selfreg rpm from?  Likely it has not been built with the same major version of EL like it should be, so the auto generated rpm requires are not met.
